# Spring 3 MVC resources and tag <mvc:resources />

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resources

I'm having some problems with the  tag (Spring 3.0.5).
I want to add images to my web application, but it doesnt work.

Here is part of my beans config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="ideafactory"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/public-resources/" cache-period="10000" />
```

Trying to add an image in a jsp file:

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/logo.png" />" alt="Idea Factory" />
```

First of all, I don't know really where to store the resources (src/main/resources/public-resources? src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/public-resources?).
Secondly, this config does not work, I can't see the image. What's wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: the solution given here: [Spring Tomcat and static resources and mvc:resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784060/spring-tomcat-and-static-resources-and-mvcresources) doesn't work either...
Added  without success.

EDIT 2: I tried to remove the mvc:resource tag and let only the mvc:default-servlet-handler> one, gave me infinite loop and stackoverflow... o_O ([Serving static content with Spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846692/serving-static-content-with-spring-3))

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Found the error:

Final xxx-servlet.xml config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Image in src/webapp/resources/logo.png

Works!

Answer (score 25):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
               location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/public-resources/"
               cache-period="10000" />
```

Put the resources under: `src/main/webapp/images/logo.png` and then access them via `/resources/images/logo.png`.

In the `war` they will be then located at `images/logo.png`. So the first location (`/`) form `mvc:resources` will pick them up.

The second location (`classpath:/WEB-INF/public-resources/`) in `mvc:resources` (looks like you used some roo based template) can be to expose resources (for example js-files) form jars, if they are located in the directory `WEB-INF/public-resources` in the jar.

Comment: Would have helped me, even if it's in fact src/main/webapp/resources/images/logo.png

Comment: @Nanocom: I introduced the images folder to make it more clear. But the "resources" path of the url is "consumed" by the mvc-tag--mapping, so it must not be in the path of the folder anymore! Except you do it the way you descriped it in your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

As said by @Nancom

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

So for clarity lets our image is in

```
resources/images/logo.png"
```

The **location** attribute of the **mvc:resources** tag defines the base directory location of static resources that you want to serve. It can be images path that are available under the `src/main/webapp/resources/images/` directory; you may wonder why we have given only **/resources/** as the location value instead of `src/main/webapp/resources/images/`. This is because we consider the `resources` directory as the base directory for all resources, we can have multiple sub-directories under `resources` directory to put our images and other static resource files.

The second attribute, **mapping**, just indicates the request path that needs to be mapped to this `resources` directory. In our case, we have assigned `/resource/**` as the mapping value. So, if any web **request starts** with the `/resource` request path, then it will be mapped to the `resources` directory, and the `/**` symbol indicates the recursive look for any resource files underneath the base `resources` directory.

So for url like
`http://localhost:8080/webstore/resources/images/logo.png`. So, while serving this web request, Spring MVC will consider `/resources/images/logo.png` as the request path. So, it will try to map `/resources` to the base directory specified by the **location** attribute, `resources`. From this directory, it will try to look for the remaining path of the URL, which is `/images/logo.png`. Since we have the `images` directory under the `resources` directory, Spring can easily locate the image file from the `images` directory.

So

```
 <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

gives us for given [requests] -> [resource mapping]:

`http://localhost:8080/webstore/resource/images/logo.png` -> searches in `resources/images/logo.png`

`http://localhost:8080/webstore/resources/images/small/picture.png` -> searches in `resources/images/small/picture.png`

`http://localhost:8080/webstore/resources/css/main.css` -> searches in `resources/css/main.css`

`http://localhost:8080/webstore/resources/pdf/index.pdf` -> searches in `resources/pdf/index.pdf`

Comment: You make me waste my time thinking for an hour as to why your answer doesn't work.., its `mapping="/resources/**"'` not `mapping="/resource/**"`

Comment: I am not agree with you. In that situations search in guthub:
https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=+%3Cmvc%3Aresources+location%3D%22%2Fresources%2F%22+mapping%3D%22%2Fresource%2F%2A%2A%22%2F%3E&ref=searchresults&s=indexed&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: I mean you declared it as `location="/resources/"` then `mapping="/resource/**"/`. Missing `s` Haha.

Answer (score 5):

Recommendations for resources in order to handle HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by offering static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory is to simply add the following line in the configuration file:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

It has worked for me.

Sources (Spring in Action book and http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Answer (score 3):

Different order make it works :)

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep rsouces directory in Directory
NetBeans: Web Pages
Eclipse: webapps

File: dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/theme_name/" mapping="/resources/**"  cache-period="10000"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

File: web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

In JSP File

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/default.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem before. My situation was **I didn't put all the 62 spring framework jars into the lib file** (spring-framework-4.1.2.RELEASE edition), it did work. And then I also changed the 3.0.xsd into 2.5 or 3.1 for test, it all worked out. Of course, there are also other factors to affect your result.

Answer (score 0):

[@Nanocom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8195417/1965078)'s answer works for me. It may be that lines have to be at the end, or could be because has to be after of some the `bean` class like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler" />    

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" 
               location="/resources/" 
               cache-period="10000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

In JSP, to view the image

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/slide-are.jpg">
```

In dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```