# How to display and update received image in jsp page

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new in web development (spring-mvc), my background is from android world. I'm receiving images from service every 2 second, than I'm saving them to the WEB-INF/images folder, at this time every 1 second, I'm making ajax request to retrieve and display received image. 
This is how I'm making ajax call

```
function updateImage() {
    $.get('/api/getCurrentImagePath/', function (frameImagePath) {
        $("#targetImgView").attr("src", frameImagePath);
        setTimeout(updateImage, 1000)
    })
}
```

My problem is that, when function is invoked `$("#targetImgView").attr("src", frameImagePath);`
console logs `http://localhost:8080/images/13456482154.jpg 404 not found error`
but received image path is correct.

How can I resolve this issue? or is there any better way to do, what I'm trying to do?

**P.S**

when I save images into the webapp/images folder during the running server and trying to set the path of images it does not works, but if I restart the server and statically set the path of already saved images it works

Comment: Did you try to open the received response image url in browser?

Comment: yes, it says HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369529/how-to-display-image-in-jsp-with-spring-mvc

Comment: I don't have a problem with static resources, it works fine if resource is static, but in my case it is dynamic

Comment: nope, I have tested and it makes requests every 1 second

Comment: You're right sorry. While app is running, can you see the image uploaded and open it on server images folder manually ?

Comment: yes, with no problem

Answer (score 0):

In Spring MVC, we have to options to display images

1. From another FTP server
2. From within EAR, to do so you can open images placed inside resource folder

Add this entry in dispatcher-servlet.xml

<mvc:resources mapping="/image/**" location="/resources/images/" cache-period="0"/>

You need to put images in your `webapp/resources/images` folder. After that access the image `contextPath/image/imageName.jpg`

Comment: what is the difference? now I'm saving images to the webapp/images/ dir

Comment: the difference is `resources mapping` tells spring to map the urls of images. you may [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195213/spring-3-mvc-resources-and-tag-mvcresources) for more info

Comment: when I save images into the webapp/images folder during the running server it doesnot works, but if I restart the server and statically set the path of images which were saved already it works