# reference a css file in deployed webapp

Tags: java, css, jsp, spring-mvc, web-inf

I have deployed a webapp at `localhost:8080/Project` with Project being the context name. The webapp correctly redirects the user to the index.jsp.

But the css file in this index.jsp is not found  (Error 404).

Index.jsp contains this reference:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
</html>
```

My project has the following structure in the WEB-INF folder:

```
WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
WEB-INF/css/style.css
```

I also tried to directly call the css file via url `localhost:8080/Project/css/style.css` but this didn't work as well.

---

I relocated the css folder one level up (on the same level as WEB-INF) as suggested. The problem still persists. Do I have to exclude the urls starting with `/css` in this `@Controller`? Or maybe I'm on a wrong path...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser loaded `localhost:8080/Project` and then continues to load `../css/style.css` relative to that URL, therefore trying to load `localhost:8080/css/style.css` which apparently does not work.

You should not place web resources like CSS, JS and images under `/WEB-INF` since they cannot be accessed from that location. Instead use something like

```
WEB-INF/views/index.jsp
css/style.css
```

and in the JSP write

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: changed the orginal post with additional info

Comment: @Vjeetje in case of spring you must also configure the mapping of your static resources, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195213/spring-3-mvc-resources-and-tag-mvcresources

Comment: Great !. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

WEB-INF is a private folder that is inaccessible by URL, but is accessible through the servlets Java code. You should put your html,css,js in the same folder level that the WEB-INF folder is in. That is, put them adjacent to WEB-INF, and not inside.

So a typical webapp folder will look like

```
*Name of webapp*
  |-js
     |-index.js
  |-css
     |-style.css
  |-index.html
  |-WEB-INF
     |-private files...
```

Then try

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thx for the tip :) I added the css folder one level up like you suggested. The problem still persists. Maybe it has something to do with my @Controller I defined? I changed the original post with extra info.