# springmvc maven link files in jsp file

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, server-side-includes

I use eclipse, springmvc and maven. I created a folder under

Web-Content --> WEB-INF -->  resources

I added the following into my servlet:

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Then I try to include a picture into my index.jsp file.(Web-Content->index.jsp)

```
<img src = "/resources/images/Logo.png" />
```

But it's not loading my image. I tryed many tutorials but it doesn't work. I guess I'm something basic wrong. Can you tell me whats wrong?

EDIT:

my serlvet got this

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

In my jsp file I did this:

```
<img src="<c:url value="/resources/logo.png" />"/>
```

I got resource folders with the logo.png file in the following places:

```
main->resources
main->webapp->resources
main->webapp->WEB-INF->resources
```

It still doesn't work
I also tried :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
               location="/, classpath:/WEB-INF/public-resources/"
               cache-period="10000" />
```

and include the picture with

```
/resources/images/logo.png
```

and the picture located in

```
src/main/webapp/images/logo.png
```

doesnt't work for me

EDIT:

I guess it this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

got no effect to the program. I can always acces the url `http://localhost:8080/test/resources/logo.png`
doenst matter if I got this mvc line in my serlvet or not. If I change

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

to

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources1/**" location="/resources/" />
```

I can't acces to the file with `http://localhost:8080/test/resources1/logo.png` but with `http://localhost:8080/test/resources/logo.png`

Greets Sam

Comment: If you're using Maven, you shouldn't have any `WebContent` folder. That is probably the cause of your problems: you should try to respect the [standard directory structure for Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: Ok. I created a "dynamic Web project" in eclipse and then transferd it into a maven project. Thats the wrong way?

Comment: Yep, that's not the right way to do it. You should first create a Maven project of packaging `war`.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to change my current project?

Comment: There isn't an easy way that I know of. Your best bet would to create a new project and copy the previous files to their rightful place in the new project.

Comment: I changed my project like you said. I got now the folder src-->main-->webapp-->WEB-INF-->resources-->images. I still cant include the picture.

Comment: Okay. Could you refer to that post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8195213/1743880

Comment: I edit my post. I tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside, while it is probably not best to make an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project and convert it to a Maven project through Eclipse, it will work, because Eclipse will put an entry into your POM that points to the WebContent directory. Have a look you will probably find it there. There is nothing wrong with making a Dynamic Web Project per se, but I typically change the initial directory configuration to match maven's expectations in the Wizard and convert to a maven project right away. Much easy to work on the POM than copy jars to the lib directory.

Otherwise, the `resources` directory you referring to should be in the root of your `war` file. The best way to get it there is to put `resources` at the root of your `WebContent` directory, not under `WEB-INF`. Try moving it there, open the .war file and inspect the contents to be sure it is in the root, and you should be good to go.