# Why resource file does not load in spring-mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I added below mvc:resource tag into servlet.xml but My application is not getting any resource file. I am trying to develop xml based spring mvc application. why resource file is not loading?

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/welcome.htm" 
        class="com.debasish.common.controller.HelloWorldController" />
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/test/**"></mvc:resources>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

Comment: can you share your whole xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14905265/7765316) try to change the order of mapping and location like this

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/client/**" location="/optimized-scripts/visualize/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine after rearrange the mapping and location ...